# Multiple authentication systems

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I've 2 tables, `Users` and `Customers` and 2 different actions for them. so I need 2 authentication system. Users login with username and password, and customers login with and id and password.

I know cake default `AuthComponent` can handle just 1 model, `User` model. because 'userModel' can be string not array (isn't it?).

How can I use it with 2 models (and tables) with 2 login pages and 2 .... .

(note: I can't combine the 2 tables. they have different schemas)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to maintain 2 different Auth systems, I highly recommend you look into ACLs and AROs.  This will allow you to associate users with different access groups - in your case you could have groups like 'Internal'<sup>1</sup> and 'Customers', and each new user account is a member of one group or the other.

You can then grant permissions at a group level.  Customer users have access to their content, Internal users have access to different content.

There is a good tutorial in the new CakePHP book:  [Simple Acl controlled Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html)

<sup>1 *I assume when you refer to 'users' generically you mean internal users, but feel free to adapt the terminology and group names to your particular situation.*</sup>

Comment: as i said, 2 tables have different schema, and i cant combine them.

Comment: @kikio I'm not suggesting you combine your tables.  I'm suggesting that you simplify your design so that you have 1 users table and associate the users with their related data & actions.  I understand what you are asking, and I'm telling you it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would presume 2 separate logins areas or a radio button to suggest which login they are attempting.

Use that input as which table to auth against then your code should follow the same path.

```
if (customer) {
 do customer stuff;
} elseif (user) {
 do user stuff;
} else {
 you didn't login;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the registration forms for them try to get their data into different databases. So that you can treat them differently. For this purpose check the submit button ids and direct the data to appropriate tables. When inserting put id's as auto increments.

Comment: different databases use by 1 app?!

Comment: Sorry just think it as two tables, and use your form button ids to distinguish them

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against discriminating users from customers in this situation. These issues can be resolved using roles. Before jumping to design, please read about [Authentication, Authorization and Audit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAA_protocol) and [Role-Based Access Control](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/documents/design_implementation/Intro_role_based_access.htm).

From my understanding, this is an overview of the authentication process (note that I am not a security expert):

The identification phase is concerned with obtaining user credentials. A simple form that retreives user's name and password would suffice.

The authentication phase represents the process that maps user credentials to an user. Basically, it identifies a identity provider and uses it to obtain an user id for the user credentials provided.

Viewed like services, they look something like this:

```
// You can have many IdentityProviders. This mecanism allows you to extend your
// authentication system so you can use any mechanism (WebDav, Kerberos, etc).
IIdentityProvider
{
    // Returns a pozitive id if the user is found and the credentials are valid
    // or zero if user credentials are invalid (or negative numbers that represent
    // error codes).
    UserID GetUser(UserCredentials)
}

IAuthenticationService
{
    Session SignIn(UserCredentials)
    void SignOut(Session)
}

DefaultIdentityProvider : IIdentityProvider
{
    // Search the user in your database.
    UserID GetUser(UserCredentials credentials)
}

AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    IIdentityProvider[] identityProviders

    Session SignIn(UserCredentials credentials)
    {
        IIdentityProvider provider = identityProviders[credentials.Type]
        Session session = null

        if (provider)
        {
            UserID userID = provider.GetUser(credentials)

            if (userID > 0)
            {
                session = new Session
                session.UserID = userID
            }
        }

        return session
    }

    void SignOut(Session session)
    {
        delete session
    }
}
```

The autorization system says what can a user do with a *resource*. Resources can be any entity that your application manages. They have a *type* and an *ID*. Optionally, they can be part of one or more *categories*. Users can execute certain *operations* on a resource, depending on its type and categories. This is defined by a *permission*. Permissions are grouped in *roles*. You can assign zero or more roles to an user.

In your example, a customer is a role. A resource is, for example, a product. A product is represented by the Product type, it has an ID and can have some categories associated ("Electronics" and "Dangerous"). Operations can be viewed as variations of Create/Read/Update/Delete verbs. Now, the Customer role would contain a set of permissions that explicitely states what a user having this role can do with the managed resources. For example, a Customer can only Read certain informations about the product, but cannot Create, Update or Delete a product. Note that if a user has more than one role associated, it gains all the permissions from that roles (an union operation, not an intersection).

This only scratches the surface. For further reading, you can find on the Internet more articles that explain these concepts alot better. This is meant to point you in the right direction.